# iOS app - how to get data from app store?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to develop an app that is going to search for apps in the app store and suggest the best of them to the user depending on the query. So my question is:

Is it possible to retrieve data from the app store? If so, how?? Maybe someone can point to the right direction. Thank you very much in advance!

P.S. My app is like [this one](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appdeals-get-paid-apps-for/id350030137?mt=8).

Comment: I imagine your example use a backend somewhere that "harvest" updates from Apple as I think the download amount is way too much for a app to handle by itself for a "good" experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention at that point in the Apple Review Guideline

> 12.1 Applications that scrape any information from Apple sites (for example from apple.com, iTunes Store, App Store, iTunes Connect, Apple Developer Programs, etc) or create rankings using content from Apple sites and services will be rejected
>
> 2.25 Apps that display Apps other than your own for purchase or promotion in a manner similar to or confusing with the App Store will be rejected